# Twitter Single Sign On OAuth PHP without third party API

Tags: php, curl, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I have been given a task to develop a a single sign on system using Twitter and I am not allowed to use third party API's. I am however allowed to use CURL and PHP. What would be the best way to do this. so far I have this but it does not work. It outputs the error "Failed to validate oauth signature and token"

I would like some advice on how to go about doing this.

```
$fields = array(
            'oauth_callback'        => 'http://www.mydomain.co.uk/redirect.php'
        );

        //url-ify the data for the POST
        foreach( $fields as $key=>$value ) {
            $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
        }

        rtrim( $fields_string, "" );

        echo $fields_string;

        $curl = curl_init( "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token" );

        //Send auth data to twiter
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, count( $fields ) );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string );

        //Will return json object
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

        $result = curl_exec($curl);

        //debugger
        if( $debug ){
            if( ! curl_errno( $curl ) ) {
                $info = curl_getinfo( $curl );
                echo 'Took ' . $info[ 'total_time' ] . ' seconds to send a request to ' . $info[ 'url' ];
            }
        }


        curl_close( $curl );

        echo $result;
```

Comment: "it does not work": What does not work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Failed to validate oauth signature and token

Comment: Your `rtrim()` doesn't do anything since you provided an empty string. You shoud use `http_build_query()` to encode your parameters. `CURLOPT_POST` expects a boolean. You should use `curl_error()` to find out what's happening. There might be something wrong with the parameters but we don't see them. Can you show us what parameters you include in `$fields` ?

Comment: In that case you need to develop a full fledged OAuth client, which is not trivial. If you cannot use third party libraries (ridiculous by the way), please consider reading third party OAuth code so that you get signatures right. And read up on the OAuth 1.0a specification, from what I can see in your code you have not implemented anything that looks even remotely like a OAuth request token request.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use of the PEAR HTTP_OAUTH library.  There is no reason to re-invent the wheel.